# Можно ли из файлов бд sql сделать dump?

Tags: mysql

Умер сервер, все что удалось вытащить это саму папку с файлами sql, каждая база в своей папке. Можно ли через что то прогнать эти файлы и получить dump или как то привести эти файлы к жизни? Сервер и условия восстановить не удастся.

[image: вот так это выглядит]

Comment: на другом сервере поставьте ту же версию mysql, создайте пустую БД и в полученную папку положите эти файлы. не факт что поможет, лучше бы кроме этих файлов взять еще те, что на одну папку выше, ibdata1 и другие рядом.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/81775/, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911/207449?

Comment: Судя по именам - вордпресс. Надеюсь, какие ТОЧНО были версии MySQL и вордпресса - знаете? Ставите - получаете структуру. Потом стоп MySQL, замена файлов, пуск MySQL, repair таблиц. Можно попробовать discard/import tablespace - но помнится мне, что без .cfg оно не работает.